# How to change the kendo dropdownlist default display text by value?

Tags: jquery, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've a kendo dropdownlist which displays a primary location. I want the dropdown to set to this primary location as the default location when I click on reset.

I'm using this:

```
$("#dropDownList").val(20);
$("#dropDownList").trigger("change");
```

It's internally changing the value, but the display text does not change.

I tried the following options but nothing seems to be changing the default text:

```
$('#dropDownList option[Value=20]').attr('selected', 'selected');
$('select#dropDownList').val('20');
```

Comment: Could you please provide your dropdownlist code in order to see your problem. There are ways both with javascript and razor to achieve this via the Select method of the kendo asp.net mvc

Answer (score 1):

For a `kendoDropDownList` control, you need to do the following:

```
                var data = [
                    { text: "Black", value: "1" },
                    { text: "Orange", value: "20" },
                    { text: "Grey", value: "3" }
                ];

                // create DropDownList from input HTML element
                $("#dropDownList").kendoDropDownList({
                    dataTextField: "text",
                    dataValueField: "value",
                    dataSource: data,
                    index: 0,
                    change: onChange
                });

                var dropDownList= $("#dropDownList").data("kendoDropDownList");

                dropDownList.select(function(dataItem) {
                    return dataItem.value === "20"; //20 is selected now
                });
                dropDownList.trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically want this then which sets the selected option to the value you want.

```
$('#dropDownList').on('change', function(){
     $('#dropDownList option:selected').val('20');
});
```